# How to generate dynamic controls in custom HTML helper without loosing much on performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to render some extra controls specified in the XML file on runtime.
I have currently created custom html helpers overriding built in helpers.
They simply check whether a currently rendered field should have some extra field being render below. 
It works fine.

However, as the page I added this behavior to is large, there are tens of different controls, the time it takes to load the page has gone up to couple minutes.

Anyone has any idea to improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you reading from the XML File every time? Maybe caching the file contents can save some roundtrips to the disk.

Comment: Yes I am using caching. The XML file is loaded. Then I simply check whether the currently render control is in the collection, if it is I render an extra control. 
I'm wondering whether there is a better way to do that from the architectural point of view?

Comment: if you've got "tens of controls", maybe time to think about a UI redesign. That's more than enough to confuse your users. Assuming you mean form controls.

Comment: I wish I could redesign UI. Unfortunately there is no time to do that at the moment and I need to fix performance issue.

Comment: redesigning your UI will fix your performance issue for you :-). If that really will take too long, then you'll have to sort this. How are you caching the XML file contents? Have you considered using a database instead?